# Struts2 Spring Hibernate Jar file conflict

Tags: hibernate, spring, jar, struts2

I am developing a sample application in Struts2+Spring+Hibernate ..

When i add jar for struts2 , Spring and Hibernate in my lib folder.. Its not running. Its because of jar files conflict..

**Is there anyway to select correct jar files for these technologies ???? If i upgrade a jar with new version, it makes error.. Is there anyway to tell what are all the jar files should i include(update) when i change(update) a jar file.**

If i add struts2-core-2.2.3.1.jar and xwork-core-2.1.6-jdk14.jar in simple struts2 application.. Struts tags are not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: **[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)**

Comment: or Ivy if you want to stick to Ant for build

Comment: well you need OGNL.jar,freemarker.jar,commons-fileupload.jat,commons-io.jar also.Still i sugest to go with `Maven` or `Lvy`

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem I solved it using JarJar.  http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/ using this you can repackage the jars.

What you have to do is to repackage all the hibernate and its supporting jars in to one jar.  Similarly you can repackage Struts with its supporting versions of jars.

For example commos-logging is used hibernate and Struts but different version you can solve the problem by JarJar..